# What does this nginx error "rewrite or internal redirection cycle" mean?

Tags: nginx

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2013/05/04 23:43:35 [error] 733#0: *3662 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "kowol.mysite.net"
HTTP/1.1", host: "www.joesfitness.net"
2013/05/05 00:49:14 [error] 733#0: *3783 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / http://www.qq.com/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.qq.com"
2013/05/05 03:12:33 [error] 733#0: *4232 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "joesfitness.net"
```

I am getting these from nginx error log, I don't have a "kowol" sub domain, I don't have any links to qq.com or joesfitness.net on my site. Whats going on?

Edit: Nginx default config:

```
server {
    listen   8080; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:8080 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

It's a strange one all right, though I'm going to bet the problem is with:

```
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

The problem here is that the second parameter here, `$uri/`, causes each of the files in your `index` directive to be tried in turn. If none are found, it then moves on to `/index.html`, which causes the same `location` block to be re-entered, and since it still doesn't exist, you get an endless loop.

I would rewrite this as:

```
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to return a 404 error if none of the index files you specified in the `index` directive exist.

---

BTW, those requests you are seeing are [Internet background noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise). In particular, they are probes to determine whether your web server is an open proxy and can be abused to hide a malicious user's origin when he goes to perform malicious activity. Your server isn't an open proxy in this configuration, so you don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way one could block/ban these kind of probes?

Comment: Not really, just feed them a nice 404 and they'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: What's "funny" is that default config on ubuntu 13.10 has `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` and `index index.php index.html index.htm;` set. resulting in the error in the question. Not so for 12.04 and 14.04, so less likely to happen on a server.

Comment: My problem was that I'm running Laravel (with vue-router) so I needed to change /index.html to /index.php

Comment: /index.php?`$query_string` passing query sting might be necessary for some cases

Comment: You just saved my life :)

Answer (score 21):

You will also get this error message if your `index.php` is entirely missing.

Comment: Yes, in my case I made a mistake putting the path on the root parameter.

Comment: `index.html` in my case

Answer (score 12):

This was annoying. It was working a few weeks ago, and it failed on me when I tried today.

I believed an upgrade of Ubuntu `nginx` package cause the default directory of where Ubuntu kept the standard index files changed, so the line:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
```

Won't work anymore as the location of the files are at `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

To fix, one can just change the root pointer to the correct directory, or create a symlink to the new directory:

```
cd /usr/share/nginx
sudo ln -s html www
```

Works for me.

Comment: You're right! Exactly! Thank you so much bro

Answer (score 5):

Had this error today, spend a few hours figuring the cause. Turned out someone deleted all the site's files.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem yesterday because I was testing nginx over a proxy server that had cached a redirect that no longer existed.  The solution for me was to `$ sudo service squid3 restart` on the squid3 proxy server I was connecting through.

Comment: Notice I shared this answer with good intentions.  There are multiple reasons for this error and it takes a while to figure out the proxy caching one.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another case when this happens. As in the accepted answer, in general, this happens when a sequence of locations being tried and then sort of internal redirect loop (never-ending) is created.

It sometimes manifests with bad NGINX config, and even with restrictive chmod (in some lockdown configs). Here's example.

Suppose that you have `index.php` front controller, as in the usual:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~\.php {
   ...
}
```

You mostly serve SEO URLs like `/some/thing` through your `index.php`.

But as usual, there are some PHP files that you need to be exposed directly (thus the `location ~\.php` and not `location = /index.php`.

Also suppose that your `index.php` was `chmod`-ded to 0400 for security lockdown.

Everything still works fine in this case, as long as the file is owned by the "PHP-FPM user". NGINX does not need to read the file, because it merely passes its filename to PHP-FPM for execution and gets back the FastCGI response.

Then you want to handle a case of what happens when someone visits `/non-existent.php` because with this rather standard config you would get `No input file specified.` for that case.

To deal with this, some folks add:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
```

Well, of course `if` is evil as per nginx, but that's not about it. Everything will now break with the redirection cycle error. Why?

Because this sequence happens in a loop:

- When `/some/page` URL is requested, nginx enters `location /`, doesn't find a real file and turns it to `/index.php`
- It then enters `.php` location block and tries to check if it can read `index.php`. Since it *can't*, it rewrites it to the same `index.php` then arrives back to `.php` again.

Comment: Thank you, **Danila Vershinin**!
This helped for me: location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }

Answer (score 1):

you can try removing the index.html from default.conf "try_files" syntax:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string $uri/index.html;
```

with this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

what I realize that nginx is trying to resolve index.html by index.php but on this line it goes back to index.html and it keeps on cycle

Answer (score 0):

Please check this directory too ;

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled (Debian dist.)
```

there is file that named as default and this file linked to your website conf. even you change your `nginx_conf` this file be valid for nginx server.